# Iterating over and performing inline updates to Spark Dataset rows

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Java 8 and Spark 2.4.x here. Again, I need help using the **Java** (*not* Scala) API!

I'm trying to iterate over all the rows of a `Dataset`, and, for each row, run a series of computations that will update the values of that particular row's columns. I understand that `Datasets` are immutable, and so this is my best attempt thus far:

```
// what we are ranging over and generating output based on
Dataset input = getSomehow();

// the output DS; must have same schema/columns as 'input'
// and will also have the same # of rows but MAY have different
// column values in each row
Dataset output = input;

input.foreach(row -> {

  // this will hold the new values we compute below
  // each key matches the name of a column we wish to update
  // each value is the new value of the row's column
  Map<String,Object> rowMap = new HashMap<>();

  // do complex computation that will update 0+ 'columns' on
  // the 'row' (key/value pairs in the map)
  if (someComplexLogicIsTrue()) {
    // just an example; here 'price' is a column on 'input'
    rowMap.put("price", 29.99);
  }

  // now we want to take all the key/value pairs from the rowMap and use
  // them to update this row's column values (more specifically, any columns
  // whose names match a key in the rowMap)
  for (String key : rowMap.keySet()) {

    // compiler error: variable used in lambda expression should be final
    // or effectively final
    output = input.withColumn(key, functions.lit(rowMap.get(key)));

  }

});
```

Again, I'm looking to:

1. Iterate all the rows of a dataset, and for each row:
2. Use the values of some of its columns to update other columns (but just for that row) using some custom/complex logic (that's outside the scope of this question)
3. Produce an 'output' dataset that has all the computations applied to each of its rows

**Any clues as to how I could accomplish this in the Java API?** Thanks in advance!

Comment: that;s not how Spark works. RDDs and Dateframes are immutable, use `map` operation if you want to do something on your data - and this will always return a new Dataframe

Comment: Oh good to know @UninformedUser (+1) - thanks! OK, so let's _scratch_ the `forEach` and replace it with `map` (**or should it be `flatMap`?**), can you provide an answer that shows the type of update I'm looking to perform using a map function instead? Say we have both a `price` column (numeric/floating point) and a `color` column (string) and want to use a map function to update `price` by adding 2.50 to it if `color == "red"`. How could I accomplish that with a map function like you propose? Thanks again!

Comment: if your rows have columns then you probably have Dataset<Row> and it is Dataframe, so you can avoid using .map and do all your steps using Spark SQL api. You could add example input and output dataset for better understanding your problem

Comment: Thanks @chlebek and +1 I'll look into your suggestions, and I can confirm that I have a `Dataset<Row>`. In the meantime, are there things you can do with the Spark SQL API that you simply can't do with `map()` and the other RDD functions, or is it that its just (arguably) _easier_ to do things with Spark SQL than with the RDD functions?